# How to use CoreData to store the best scores for a game (iOS)

Tags: ios, core-data

I've looked at a number of SO questions ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599814/how-to-use-coredata-to-store-the-best-score-for-a-game-in-xcode-6))..

I don't have one score though. I have an app that tests people's ability to learn another language. So I have a score for each word.

I can read from the model, but I don't know how to set an incremental value.

A score is attached to each word in each language. Ideas would be great.

Right now, my database model is a single entity as follows:

[image]

I'm at the point where I have the correct result but don't know what to do with it..

I havent gotten beyond this when my brain blew.

```
-(void) incrementScore {
    NSLog (@"incrementScore");
     WordEntity * word = nil;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int languageKey = [defaults integerForKey:DEFAULT_KEY_LANGUAGE_NUMBER];

    if (languageKey == 0) {
        currentScore  = [word.greekScore integerValue];

    } else {
        currentScore = [word.englishScore integerValue];
    }



    if (languageKey == 0) {
        //NSNumber *tempNumber;
        //word.greekScore setValue:currentScore forKey:<#(NSString *)#>
       // word.greekScore = [word.greekScore +1 ];
        currentScore  = [word.greekScore integerValue];

    } else {
        currentScore = [word.englishScore integerValue];
    }
    currentScore = currentScore + 1;
```

Comment: is your question how you should save these new values? Also you show the Core data table above but in the code you are using NSUserDefauls to extract the values.. which are you really using?

Comment: Hi, the NSUserDefaults are for simple switches, like number of quiz rounds, or which language is primary. I can't use these for hundreds, if not thousands of words.

Answer (score 1):

the new farmville age way of doing this is to use gamecenter instead of
killing a fly with a coredata cannon

I suppose that does not answer your question, does it

Comment: I think GameCenter is for sharing game scores with others, but I'll take a look. You are right about CoreData being a cannon. If I could just stash an array somewhere, that would be quite adequate. ideas?

Comment: How about a property list (plist) ?

Comment: nothing wrong using coredata cannon for a miniscule task, depends on the goal, if you want to learn coredata that's a valid application of coredata, if you have other things to fry then game center is cheaper